# Como fazer Colisão em jogo com Java 2D plataforma?

Tags: java, detecção-de-colisão

Eu estou tentando a vários dias fazer um método de colisão que me retorne ou me diga os lados de um retangulo que se estão sendo colididos. Eu já Utilizei o método *intersects* mas isso só me retorna que esta havendo a colisão em geral, preciso diferenciar as partes que se estão sendo colididas.

Em outras palavras eu tenho um jogo do megaman, Tenho a gravidade funcionado da seguinte forma:

- **se a gravidade for < que 0 então esta pulando**
- **se a gravidade for > que 0 então esta caindo**

A ideia é fazer com que quando meu boneco estiver colidindo com a parte de cima de um retângulo a gravidade pare, e quando o mesmo esta colidindo com a parte laterais do retângulo a gravidade não pare, mas impeça ele invadir o retângulo. ***E por esse motivo que as colisões que eu preciso saber quais partes estao sendo colididas***.

Comment: Cara, quando você está em cima de uma caixa a gravidade para? Não! Então não tem porque você anular a gravidade... simplesmente garanta que o personagem colida com a caixa e não invada a mesma. Permita que a gravidade continue atuando. Você vai anular a gravidade através da força normal da caixa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fonte: http://www.sirmacstronger.eti.br/jogos2d/conceitos2.htm

**Colisão por pixels**

Se você necessita realizar uma detecção perfeita, você pode fazer a detecção em nível de pixels. É importante ter em mente, como você poderá constatar, que esse tipo de procedimento embora eficaz é extremamente oneroso em termos de processamento. **Com base nos pixels em que for detectada a sobreposição, é possível saber em qual lado de um retângulo ocorreu a colisão.**

O ponto principal para começar a definir uma função (ou método) de detecção de colisão por pixels é entender que as imagens bitmaps são armazenadas como números inteiros que se repetem ao longo do mapa de bits. A cada cor é associado um número. Em geral, à cor transparente é associado o número 0 (zero).

Para otimizar o processo, primeiramente definimos se houve uma colisão entre os polígonos circundantes do objeto (supondo retângulos). No caso de não haver colisão entre os polígonos circundantes é impossível haver colisão entre os objetos. Por outro lado, caso haja colisão entre os polígonos circundantes então existe a possibilidade de que houve colisão entre os objetos.

Observe que no primeiro caso nosso trabalho está terminado. No segundo caso, temos que definir qual foi a área de colisão (que no caso de retângulos circundantes nos dá um novo retângulo). Chamaremos esse retângulo de retângulo de sobreposição. Ele é a área onde os dois retângulos dos objetos se sobrepuseram.

Agora o que devemos fazer é percorrer essa área do retângulo de sobreposição nas duas imagens (pixel por pixel) e determinar se em ambas as imagens há um mesmo pixel do retângulo de sobreposição onde as duas imagens apresentam cor não transparente. Se ambas as imagens dos objetos apresentam pixels não-transparentes na mesma posição dentro do retângulo de sobreposição então houve de fato colisão.

O pseudo-código abaixo mostra esse procedimento:

```
/*retorna 0 se não houve colisão, ou 1 se houve colisão*/
int Função ColisaoPorPixel(objeto1, objeto2)
{

      //Define os pontos corners dos objetos
        left1 = objeto1.x;
      left2 = objeto2.x;
      right1 = objeto1.x + object1.largura;
      right2 = objeto2.x + object2.largura;
      top1 = objeto1.y;
      top2 = objeto2.y;
      bottom1 = objeto1.y + object1.altura;
      bottom2 = objeto2.y + object2.altura;

/*Teste de rejeição para colisão de polígonos circundantes*/
      if (bottom1 < top2) returna(0);
      if (top1 > bottom2) returna(0);

      if (right1 < left2) returna(0);
      if (left1 > right2) returna(0);


/*Se chegamos aqui é porque pode haver colisão, descubra o retângulo de sobreposição*/
      if (bottom1 > bottom2) 
            over_bottom = bottom2;
      else 
            over_bottom = bottom1;

      if (top1 < top2) 
            over_top = top2;
      else 
            over_top = top1;

      if (right1 > right2) 
            over_right = right2;
      else 
            over_right = right1;

      if (left1 < left2) 
            over_left = left2;
      else 
            over_left = left1;


    // Agora situa as áreas de comparação nos dois objetos
    i = ((over_top – objeto1.y) * objeto1.largura) + over_left;
    pixel1 = objeto1.frames[objeto1.curr_frame] + i;

    j = ((over_top - objeto2.y) * objeto2.largura) + over_left;
    pixel2 = objeto2.frames[objeto2.curr_frame] + j;

/* Agora começa a varrer todos o retângulo de sobreposição, testando se o correspondente pixel de 
     cada bitmap de cada objeto,para ver se ambos são  
     diferentes de zero
     */

    for (i=0; i < over_height; i++) 
    {
        for (j=0; j < over_width; j++) 
        {
            if (objeto1[pixel1].cor > 0) && (objeto2[pixel2].cor > 0) 
            {
                  //houve colisão
                  return(1);
            }
            pixel1++;
            pixel2++;
        }
        pixel1 += (objeto1.largura - over_width);
        pixel2 += (objeto2.largura - over_width);
    }

/* Pior caso do algoritmo!  Varremos o retângulo de sobreposição e não encontramos nenhuma colisão*/ 

    return(0);
};
```

Como foi dito acima, é importante entender, que esse algoritmo, embora seja completamente eficaz, é muito oneroso. Para muitos objetos se movendo na tela ao mesmo tempo, para os quais você tenha que testar colisão, esse procedimento pode simplesmente fazer seu jogo ficar quase que travado de tão lento.

Considerando a forma dos objetos, seus tamanhos e o quanto realista o jogo precisa ser. Podemos pensar em formas de combinar as técnicas de detecção de colisão aprendidas para formar um tratamento que embora seja mais complexo, pois tratar vários casos, também pode ser bastante eficiente: a detecção hierárquica de colisão.

Comment: O site esta dando um erro 404 D: